# Populate dictionary asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a simple `foreach` loop (as below) that iterates over a collection and makes an async API call to fetch data based on the current iterator value.

```cs
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    var usersInGroup = await this.tableauService.GetUsersInTableauGroup(group.Id);

    // do work with `usersInGroup`
}
```

Instead of making an API call each iteration, I want to create an async task for each API call and execute them all at the same time, with the results populating a dictionary keyed by `group.Id`. Is this possible?

In my head, the code would look something like:

```cs
IList<Task<string[]>> tasks = new List<Task<string[]>>();
IDictionary<string, string[]> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    tasks.Add(this.tableauService.GetUsersInTableauGroup(group.Id));
    // Somehow define callback of each task to hydrate dictionary
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Task.WhenAll() returns all the values of the tasks, so you can do something like this:

```
var tasks = groups
  .Select(async g => new 
  {
    g.Id, 
    Values = await this.tableauService.GetUsersInTableauGroup(g.Id)
  });
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
var dictionary = results
  .ToDictionary(r => r.Id, r => r.Values);
```

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh: No, that produces a `Task<{anonymous}>`-returning `Func<>`. (Otherwise, how would `Task.WhenAll()` await those tasks and get their results?)

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh it's not returning void, its a `Func<T,TResult>`

Comment: @StriplingWarrior seems good solution, i wasn't able to get my head around, need coffee probably...

Comment: Thanks. Let me know if there's any part of it I can help to explain better.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks @StriplingWarrior

Answer (score 0):

You want to parallelize the `for`, not the work inside each loop cycle. Use `Parallel.ForEach`.

Comment: Only key operations aren't thread safe, reading the keys is, and he doesn't show in his code how he uses the dictionary. A plain `Dictionary<>` could *potentially* be fine.

Comment: OP specifically says he's trying to populate the dictionary, which implies he'll be calling `Add`.

Comment: ... or use: ```ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>``` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
        public async Task<(string name, int id)> Aggregate(int id)
        {
            var result = await this.tableauService.GetUsersInTableauGroup(id);
            return (result, id);
        }

...
            var tasks = await Task.WhenAll(groups.Select(g => Aggregate(g.Id)));

            var dict = tasks.ToDictionary(k => k.id, k => k.name);
```

It will run all of the API calls asynchronously, once all of those request are finished, we can safely create a dictionary from the results